# How to handle Lazy Initialization Exception in hibernate without touch xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

"org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy "

```
Request request = new Request();

String t1 = request.getRequestTitle();
String t2 = request.getStatusMain().getStatusValue();
```

how to handle this issue without changing xml file

Comment: I think you need to add a little context in order to get help. How do the mapping files look like? In which context do you call getRequest()? What does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: That's a little vague but basically that exception happens when you try to access a reference to another entity (or a collection of entities) that's not initialized yet (hence lazy) and the hibernate session is already closed. So either make the session live longer or (probably better) load the data you need before leaving the scope of that session.

Answer (score 0):

you did not provided much information, but I think what you need is

```
Hibernate.initialize
```

to initialize your lazy list

Comment: In request Object I have StatusMain Object, while I am calling this like request.getStatusMain().getStatus();   at that time I am getting this exception...